# CSS Reset is not working on my machine but is working on codepen

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS reset as shown below but however, it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<!--Document type declaration-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <!--Linking to our CSS file-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <!--Character encoding of the page-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Learning</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="introduction">
    <h1>H1 Text</h1>
    <h2>H2 Text</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
/* CSS Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: white;
}

.introduction {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

[Updated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d46x8.png)

I am starting to doubt it's my machine because the CSS reset works on CodePen.

Thanks for looking into this silly question. If you need more information please don't hesitate to ask me.

Edit:
I have uploaded my code to Codepen and it is working fine. Added new screenshot.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPBVLV

Added my HTML and CSS code.

Comment: plss add  * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} after all the reset.css ends

Comment: Hi Sonia. I am sorry I couldn't quite understand what you mean. Could you kindly explain it to me what's the problem? 

I am currently using this reset in my main CSS file.

Comment: Did you paste your entire css to codepen ? Maybe the reset rule is overwritten by another in your css file

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. There isn't enough information in the question to identify the problem.

Comment: Hi @WirelessKiwi, Yes I did paste the entire CSS and HTML code. That doesn't seem to be the case as I just started the CSS portion.

Comment: Is it just the reset portion of the CSS that's not working on your local machine? Is the rest of the CSS (in the same file) working as expected?

Comment: Hi @Quentin, I have actually reproduced the code in CodePen and in my machine. But however, it only works on CodePen.

Comment: @top22 — You said that already. I've told you already that we need more information before we can identify the problem.

Comment: Hi @delinear, Yup, it's just the CSS portion not working. The other CSS code is working fine. For example, the background color, color of the div and the font color.

Comment: @Quentin, I am sorry I am new to programming. Could you guide me on how I can provide more information? I followed the guide and provided the minimal code.

Comment: I have added the code into codepen which can be found here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPBVLV

Comment: @top22 — From the guide: "Use as little code as possible **that still produces the same problem**". Where's the HTML? Where's the tiny bit of CSS to show off the red and blue areas?

Comment: @Quentin Sorry but thanks for being patient with me. I have added the new image and at the same time added my code into codepen.

Comment: @top22 — … and it still works. You need to show us the code that has the problem in it, not working code. We can't tell what is wrong with the code we can't see.

Comment: @Quentin Once again, I am so sorry and thank you for your time and patience. I do not know where the problem is because it seems right to me. 

I have posted my HTML and CSS code into the question. Sorry, if this is not what you expected.

Comment: @Quentin, I have found the problem. Thank you so much for taking your time. Is there any way I can give reputation to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

in CSS files I do not need to add `<style>`. I can just write my CSS code into the CSS file.

I am sorry everyone and especially @Quentin for looking into this silly mistake.